# About the expression of a vector in the form of a basis in infinite-dimensional normed space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

This question is about functional analysis.

**Definition (Schauder Basis)** A fixed list of unit vectors $e_{n}$ is called a Schauder basis when for any $x$ in a normed space $(X,||\cdot||)$, there are unique coefficients $\alpha_{n}$ such that
$$ x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n} e_{n} .$$
where $ x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n} e_{n} $ means that
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\left \| x-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \alpha_{n} e_{n} \right \| = 0 \quad (**).$$

But as proved by the axiom of choice, every normed vector space (either finite-dimensional or not) has a basis, but not necessary satisfying $(**)$. So how to express a vector $x$ in the form of a basis? Or, there is no nice expression? In finite-dimensional normed vector space there are no such concerns.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: In an infinite-dimensional normed vector space a Schauder basis is never a basis. Not every infinite-dimensional normed vector space has a Schauder basis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis.

Comment: Hmm, there is such concern in a finite-dimensional space. What would you say is a "nice expression" to write a vector in term of a basis in finite dimension?